# Xcode is not showing Debug View Hierarchy button

Tags: ios, xcode

Today, I noticed that my `Debug view hierarchy` button is not showing in Xcode. I don't know when it is gone. Does anyone have any idea?

My Xcode version is Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)

[image]

Comment: Are you running a Debug build or a Release build? Do the buttons in the debug bar appear when your app hits a breakpoint?

Comment: How does it connect with the View Debug hierarchy? @SwiftDevJournal

Comment: You have to be running a Debug build and hit a breakpoint to debug your app and show the buttons in the debug bar (the circled part in your screenshot), including the Debug View Hierarchy button. Without answers to the two questions I asked in the first comment, no one can know if there's an issue with Xcode or if your app is just running without hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal You do not need to hit a breakpoint for the "Debug View Hierarchy" button to appear and you do not need to hit a breakpoint to click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run the application. On simulator or on a device and make sure the view is loaded which you want to debug. Second make sure you have enough powerful Mac. I have an old MacBook Air. I wasn't able to use on that. Also make sure you are not trying to view hierarchy when you have hit a breakpoint.

Hope this works

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I forgot the case and how It was fixed. I should have put the solutions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to scheme setting of the target your debugging.

[image]

In the Run section, set build config need to Debug.
[image]

In Diagnostics setting, make sure you check Main Thread Checker and API Validation
[image]